# Mapping > (and <) to function for special indent

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I would like to map `>` (and `<`) in `normal` mode to a function such that it indents the line and keeps the cursor at the original position after performing the indent

Here my code in the file `mymodule.lua`:

```lua
local M = {}

function M.reset_cursor_pos(fct, offset, ...)
  offset = offset or 2
  -- e.g. lua require("user.utils").reset_cursor_pos(function() print('x') end)
  local _, cursor_line, cursor_col, _, _ = unpack(vim.fn.getcurpos())
  fct()
  vim.fn.setpos('.', {0, cursor_line, cursor_col + offset, 0}) -- 15G25|
end

return M
```

and the keymap in `lua`

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", ">", "<cmd>lua require('mymodule').reset_cursor_pos(function() vim.cmd[[normal >>]] end, vim.o.shiftwidth)", {})
```

or in `vim`

```
nmap > :lua require('mymodule').reset_cursor_pos(function() vim.cmd[[normal >>]] end, vim.o.shiftwidth)
```

The function execution works as intended but not the keypmap. Does anyone know how I could make the key-mapping work?

Comment: Annex: I am using `Neovim 0.8` on `Linux Mint 21 Vanessa`

Comment: If you've ended up with two accounts, we can merge them for you.

Comment: Welcome vi.SE @kraxli I think you're looking for `<Left>` and `<Right>` as keys name.

Comment: wow, so much junk for a trivial 3 line function in VimScript :(

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> are [special keys](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-special), and are anyway used for Vim special keys notation… There are [3 ways to mention such keys](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-special-keys): Use

- the [<kbd>^v</kbd> trick](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) to insert the terminal code (cons: it may work differently on some other terminal. pros: it's a standard and easy practice.) → n/a
- the [<kbd>^k</kbd>](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-K) and hit the key instead of a [defined digraph combination](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraphs-default) (cons: I never managed to do it. pros: there's alternative numbering that should work) → n/a
- the termcap entry `xx` in the form `<t_xx>` (pros: it's like the first but in a portable way. cons: depends on the absence of one `cpoptions` flag.) → [n/a](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/5/termcap/)
- the Vim [key notation](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#keycodes) (pros: it's the easiest and portable way known by all vimers. cons: depends on the absence of one `cpoptions` flag.) → `<lt>` (and `>`)